# Auth failed running command from shell script

Tags: svn, shell-script, authentication

I try to run following command from shell script:
`svn checkout http://url/ --username user --password password --non-interactive --no-auth-cache .`

It fails always with following error:

> svn: OPTIONS of 'http://url/': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (http://url)

Here the call out of my script:
`$(svn $command $url $auth --non-interactive --no-auth-cache .)`

Running the same command from the terminal works fine.
What is the difference between running from shell script and terminal?

EDIT:
Here some version information:

- OS: Porteus 1.0 based on Slackware 13.3
- Subversion: subversion-1.6.16-i486-1

Comment: Are there characters such as `&` in the URL? You should quote it with single quote `'` character.

Comment: No nothing like that. The single quote lead into **svn: '$url' does not appear to be a URL**.

Comment: Oh... it's a variable. Try double quotes `"` then. Your question isn't telling us everything...

Comment: Makes no difference I had tried it. ;)

Comment: Well, show us yer codez then. ;-)

Comment: I have added it. :)

Comment: ok... now, please show the output of `echo $url` and `echo $auth`.

Comment: The first command show it. I get that output with `echo svn $command $url $auth --non-interactive --no-auth-cache .`

Answer (score 0):

Check you are using the same svn binary in each case:

```
echo $PATH
which svn
```

And these lines before your svn call in the script and when you try it manually.

EDIT:

Maybe it's proxies. I guess show us the `env` output?

Comment: Both outputs are the same.

Comment: Yes I used the env varible *http_proxy*, but it doesn't matters because firstly it appears in both environments and secondly the webserver is in the same network and so the proxy isn't needed. Please write the next time a comment because I haven't seen your edit.

Comment: @H3llGhost - sorry I thought my edited answer would pop up for you.